# defineProps Parsing error regarding prop type: Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace;`?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

```
const props = defineProps({
  selectedData: <Record<string, string>>
});
```

there is a red line under the closing bracket, saying

> Parsing error: Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or
> `&rbrace;`?eslint Expression expected.ts(1109)

Am I defining the type incorrectly? I am not sure how else to do to it.
I was tying to follow this example given by vue.js: https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-props

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @catgirlkelly I am trying to assign the correct type to selectedData so that it's not an 'unknown' type

Comment: You are using a type as a value, which isn't valid Typescript. Don't do that. The "object literal" you are passing to that function is a type, not an object literal value.

Comment: @JaredSmith I got that error at one point too. I was trying to follow this example: https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-props

Comment: @notnoahkirby not your fault. It's either an error in the docs... or Vue is essentially using a custom parser to extend the Typescript language with their own special sauce. I don't know Vue at all, but I'm a pretty solid Typescripter and that [isn't valid Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBkFMBcGdQLYEMDWlRNAE0gMwJYB2kACgE4D2ADvLgK6EDG0+Fho0AFktAOTzQAnlUhZQAG3xoMoMpCTjQbdACM60UACs6sDXOh0yhAZ3RIyAczoJIhDbgplQkAB5IEVcZACwAKHpMLGzYeESklDQAPAAqzi7QtljwAN4AvqAAvKBpAHwAFFQRsABcoNEAlNl+oLIwhuyF1LAA3H6pfn6MbLqgjTSZIQTE5E15ydWgsJBezKIAIjxIpZEASpBdZFiRumREFgA0k9C7hBY5OW3lrb5AA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [documentation for Vue](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits):

> If you are using TypeScript, it is also possible to declare props and emits using pure type annotations.

That means you could just use:

```
const props = defineProps<{
  selectedData: Record<string, string>;
}>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Its done with generics

```
const { selectedData } = defineProps<{ selectedData: <Record<string, string>> }>()
```

Its actually in the documentation of vue, just scroll down:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reminder that I need lang="ts"